# How do you label a horizontal line when the x axis is categorical?

Tags: r, label, ggplot2

There is a [worked example](http://had.co.nz/stat405/resources/drills/ggplot2.html) that shows how to label a straight line in R using ggplot2. Please look at example 5 - "Recreate the following plot of flight volume by longitude".

How do you code if the x axis was categorical instead of continuous? How would one write the part of the syntax in geom_text that is currently

```
data = data.frame(x = - 119, y = 0)
```

I created a line

```
 + geom_text(aes(x,y, label = "seronegative"), 
             data = data.frame(x = 1, y = 20), 
             size = 4, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, angle = 0)
```

and I tried several options

```
data = data.frame(x = 1, y = 20)
data = data.frame(x = factor(1), y = 20)
#where gard is the name of one of the categories
data = data.frame(x = "gard", y = 20)
```

...but I get the error

> invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: Note that in the example you link to, a categorical x variable makes no sense, since that plot shows a continuous density estimate.

Comment: @joran You are quite correct. With respect to a graph making sense the worked example could never have a categorical x axis but with respect to the principle of plotting text labels it could easily have been categorical values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to do, since you say you try to create a line, and then your code uses `geom_text`. Assuming that you'd like to place a vertical line, with a text label oriented vertically on that line, using a categorical x variable, here's a simple example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = letters[1:5],y = 1:5)
txt <- data.frame(x = 1.5, y = 1, lab = "label")

ggplot(dat,aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    geom_vline(xintercept = 1.5) + 
    geom_text(data = txt,aes(label = lab),angle = 90, hjust = 0, vjust = 0)
```

which on my machine produces this output:

[image]

Note that I put the text labels in a separate data frame, *outside* the `ggplot` call. That is not be strictly necessary, but I prefer it as I find that it avoids confusion.

Using an x value of 1.5 for the text label works here, as would setting it to "a" if you wanted it directly on the plotted x values.

The error you're describing suggests to me a simple syntax error somewhere in your code (which you haven't completely provided). Perhaps this example will help you to spot it.

Comment: +1, and to add, when you're adding a layer that would generally expect a continuous value you can cheat by using numbers that correspond to the factor level of the categorical variable(s) for placement. aka it's not necessary to define a separate `data.frame()` it's only necessary to supply `geom_text()` with `x=` and `y=`

Comment: `geom_text(aes(x=1, y=1.5,label = lab),angle = 90, hjust = 0, vjust = 0)`

Comment: Edited to make it clear that my use of separate data frames is a style judgement.

Comment: @joran I think you were right about me having a some syntax error. No matter what I did I kept getting "invalid argument to unary operator". Eventually I got it to work. I do not know how. It may have been a stray inverted comma. This is my full code now and it works well.  ggplot(syrclia,aes(cls.grp,HPV6AB))+ geom_jitter(size=4,position=position_jitter(width=.15))+scale_y_log10()+ geom_hline(aes(yintercept=c(20,81.3,1065.6)))+xlab("group")+ylab("anti-HPV 6 GMT (mMU/ml)")+ geom_text(aes(x=c(4.2,4.2),y=c(11,33), label = c("seronegative","seropostive")), angle=90). Thanks for your help